# Selecting all column names where value is greater than 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have an undefined number of columns that have some values. for the example lets say there are 4 columns: `[a,b,c,d]` , and there is value associated with each column name, like this:

```
a   b   c   d
0   23  11  0
11  43  33  22
12  0   12  0
```

I want to write another column right next to `d`, which has the max value of the column whose value is greater than 0, for example:
Like this:

```
a   b   c   d   e
0   23  11  0   b,c
11  43  33  22  a,b,c,d
12  0   12  0   a,c
```

my attempt:

```
dic2 = {'a':[12,0,23],'b':[21,23,0],'c':[0,22,33],'d':[0,22,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic2)
df[df>0]
```

This will return the `NaN` value wherever there is zero but I don't know how do I get the column who has these `NaN` value.

Comment: b and c has values >0 (23,11),and max among them 32 ?

Comment: In your attempt, all the rows have 0s, doesn't it?

Comment: column b and c has the value >0 and then please look at the values of associated the column name a=11
b=32
c=22
d=10

Comment: so among b and c , b has the max value. which is 32

Comment: please see the updated request

Comment: yeah sorry, updated that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter values greater like `0` to boolean DataFrame and then use [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) for matrix multiplication with columns names, last remove separator by indexing with `str`:

```
df['e'] = df.gt(0).dot(df.columns + ',').str[:-1]
print (df)
    a   b   c   d      e
0  12  21   0   0    a,b
1   0  23  22  22  b,c,d
2  23   0  33   0    a,c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new column and use `max` function on all other columns

```
df['D'] = df.max(axis=1)
```

Code will check all column. If You want to specify from which columns You want to have the max value specify them like that

```
df['D'] = df[column].max(axis=1)
```

or with list of columns

```
df['D'] = df[[column1, column2]].max(axis=1)
```

Comment: no I need the columns whose value is greater than 0

Comment: "I want to write another column right next to d, which has the max value of the column whose value is greater than 0"  This code does exactly that

Comment: "whose value is greater than 0" that part is not there

Comment: What do You want it to return if there will be no values greater than 0 ? because if there will be any values greater than 0 it will return it You don't have to specify it

Comment: lets say that would Nan